# AMD Raid and Dual Boot

Tags: multi-boot, raid, raid-0

I've just upgraded my PC with a new Ryzen processor and a B550M Motherboard. I use this computer for both gaming (in a Windows-dedicated SSD) and working (in another Linux-dedicated SSD). I also have 2 1TB HDDs that I use for mass storage.

Since this new motherboard offers me the "AMD Raid" feature, I decided to combine the 2 HDDs in one RAID-0 array, for increased write/read speeds. The final disk arrangement was like this:

| Array | Disks | Raid type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Array 0 | Windows SSD | No raid |
| Array 1 | Linux SSD | No raid |
| Array 2 | HDD 0 + HDD 1 | RAID 0 |

After a clean install, I can easily boot into the Array 0 to Windows, where I can easily use both Arrays 0 and 2.

**The problem is: I want to dual-boot into Array 1, where I'd have the Linux OS and also access to the Array 2.**

It seems that AMD Raid boots to the first array, but I can't find an option to change the Array order in the BIOS setup.

I couldn't find any reference to help me in this situation. Could anyone here point me to the right path, please?